How to use correct body request for relation in strapi [ValidationError]?
Problem Description
You have a batches collection type in Strapi with the following attributes:

name: a string.
state: an enumeration.
orders: a one-to-many relation.
owner: a one-to-one relation with the plugin::users-permissions.user.

When trying to create a new batch via the Strapi REST API with the following request:
POST /api/batches
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Test Batch",
    "state": "open",
    "locale": "vi",
    "owner": "rz9blkq8c0bns6bxx81heq9w"
  }
}

You receive the following error:
{
  "data": null,
  "error": {
    "status": 400,
    "name": "ValidationError",
    "message": "Invalid key owner",
    "details": {
      "key": "owner",
      "path": "owner",
      "source": "body"
    }
  }
}



I found the reason is that you send owner as a string. You need to send the owner as an object containing the id of the related user.
POST /api/batches
{
  "data": {
    "name": "Test Batch",
    "state": "open",
    "locale": "vi",
    "owner": {
      "id": "rz9blkq8c0bns6bxx81heq9w"
    }
  }
}


I had try this but it's not working.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
